# Можете дать советы по оптимизации Vue js

Tags: vue.js

появился вопрос по оптимизации сайта на Vue. Я попробовал советы из гугла но это не сильно помогло. Может быть это нормально для SLOW 3G, но хотелось бы добиться лучшего результата.
Это пример с моего сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один только webpack загружается около 11 секунд

Можете пожалуйста ответить как улучшить загрузку

Вот скриншот Lighthouse:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот performance :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё тестировалось на Slow 3g

Comment: 1. Замеры надо производить не на девсервере (с неоптимизированной выдачей), а на продакшн сборке которая сервится локально (раз используется эмуляция скорости сети); 2. Даже если тут есть над чем поработать, что еще не факт, вопрос следует задавать о **конкретной** проблеме (о конкретном участке кода, который медленно выполняется до FMP) - конечно же, для этого надо будет сначала самостоятельно найти тот самый медленный код. По картинкам метрик с девсервера невозможно определить, что именно в приложении "тормозит"... там же все портит 11мегабайтная отладочная сборка (это нормально, ожидаемо).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: В общем, советую сделать `npm run build` и протестировать результат через локальный HTTP-сервер с настроенным кэшированием (так же используя эмуляцию сети в lighthouse). С оптимизацией изображений думаю справишься без подсказок, а по скриптам - Хром с недавнего времени научился показывать время выполнения кода прямо при просмотре скрипта через раздел "Sources" - если собрать проект с отключенной минификацией скриптов и затем замерить загрузку через раздел "Performance", увидишь в просмотре исходника такие метки: [скриншот](https://i.imgur.com/fiShnY4.png) (тут не очень показательно, сорри).

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, если что-то из этого поможет. Ждем более конкретного вопроса с кодом :)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, значительно ускорилась загрузка. Проблема была в том, что я подключал все плагины полностью ( bootstrap и google charts ). (Также сократил размер картинок) Когда я выборочно подключил и переписал scss скорость увеличилась в 2 раза

Comment: Замечательно)) А бутстрап - старый жирдяй, да еще и неудобный... лучше его вообще забыть, по-моему. Применив tailwind (конечно c PurgeCSS), можно получить размер бандла стилей примерно 5..15КБ mingzipped, в среднем (понятно, что у супертолстых приложений и стили будут толстыми, и все же преимущество чегоугодно над BS все равно сохраняется). Но и идеология у TW совсем другая нежели у BS, она не всем подходит.